# How to keep processes running after rebooting?

Tags: reboot, background-process

I'm running machine learning training process on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.
The running process is in a tmux session.

The administrator told me that the server would be down during the holidays.
I was wondering if there is any `bg` command that can restore the process after the server rebooting?
Or I can only resume training on the checkpoint model.

Training source code: https://github.com/deepinsight/insightface/tree/master/recognition/arcface_torch

Comment: Many training programs have save points where you can continue off later. Can you post a link to your training program?

Comment: Sure, I have added the link. I have found there is cfg.resume option to resume training.

Comment: I quickly checked the link and don't see how to save and restore training points. You can scroll through the 1,000 open GitHub issues and see if someone has already asked that question.

Comment: The answer is "you don't".  You can't keep running processes running when the system goes down for the system.  It cannot 'restore' the job and if the training tool does not allow saving training progress then you're not going to be able to do so.  Suspended processes don't survive reboots, because even suspended they depend on `init` and the system being online (where `init` is SystemD)

Comment: Linux support whole-process checkpoint/restore (experimentally for Docker) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRIU but it's for CPU only and doesn't support CUDA. In your code, you have PyTorch checkpoint integration so you should use that. Set `cfg.save_all_states` and `cfg.resume`